# Is there any way to automatically close filename completetion buffers in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

For example, when you open a file via C-x-C-f, you can TAB complete file names, and if there are more than one possible completions, it will pop open a completion buffer with a list of possible completions. The problem is, after you've opened the file, the window the buffer was in switches back to normal, but it doesn't close. Is there any way I can make those buffers close automatically after the file has been opened?

Comment: Do you mean you want to completely "kill" the * Completions * buffer after being used (rather than default behaviour which is just to "hide" it)?

Comment: The window configuration switches back to what it was before you try the completions (on C-x C-f for a plain emacs (`emacs -q`).  Can you give more details?  Is <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> perhaps not bound to `find-file`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it does not directly solve your problem have you considered [`ido-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) as a mechanism for opening files?

[ido-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) will bind `C-x C-f` to `ido-find-file` this allows you to interactively opening files (selecting between name collisions from within the minibuffer `C-s` and various other nifty features) I find it a much easier method of finding files and it will get rid of the `*Completions*` buffer altogether.

Comment: It has many other uses than the ones described here and is part of emacs by default (from version 22 I think). The more you read what it can do, the more you will probably like it.

Answer (score 14):

Sorry to enter really late on this but this is how I do:

```
;; Remove completion buffer when done
(add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook 
      '(lambda ()
         (let ((buffer "*Completions*"))
           (and (get-buffer buffer)
            (kill-buffer buffer)))))
```

Tested on GNU Emacs 22.x and 23.x